# JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I wanted to write a small and simple REST service using Spring Boot.
Here is the REST service code:

```
@Async
@RequestMapping(value = "/getuser", method = POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Record getRecord(@RequestBody Integer userId) {
    Record result = null;
    // Omitted logic

    return result;
}
```

The JSON object I sent is the following:

```
{
    "userId": 3
}
```

And here is the exception I got:

> WARN 964 --- [  XNIO-2 task-7]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP
>   message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
>   java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT token at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@12e7333c; line: 1, column: 1]; nested
>   exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can
>   not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT
>   token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@12e7333c; line: 1,
>   column: 1]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Obviously Jackson can not deserialize the passed JSON into an `Integer`. If you insist to send a JSON representation of a *User* through the request body, you should encapsulate the `userId` in another bean like the following:

```
public class User {
    private Integer userId;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then use that bean as your handler method argument:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public @ResponseBody Record getRecord(@RequestBody User user) { ... }
```

If you don't like the overhead of creating another bean, you could pass the `userId` as part of *Path Variable*, e.g. `/getuser/15`. In order to do that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getuser/{userId}", method = POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Record getRecord(@PathVariable Integer userId) { ... }
```

Since you no longer send a JSON in the request body, you should remove that `consumes` attribute.

Comment: I know the problem is with the Jackson Object Mapper, but I'm not really know the JSON object sending via HTTP. My original tipp was that the problem is with my JSON object.
Thanks your answer Ali Dehghani!

Comment: There is no other way to send a simple Integer in POST method without use the PathVariable annotation?
Are there any other de/serialization tech beside Jackson that can be deserialize a simple Integer in the request body?

Comment: Instead of `application/json`, you can send a key-value pair, e.g. `userId=15` in the request body using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: if not @PathVariable you can use @RequestParam("userId") that will be the query parameter into URI, and will be treated as "?userId=15" a the end of the your service URI.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps you are trying to send a request with JSON text in its body from a Postman client or something similar like this:

```
{
 "userId": 3
}
```

This cannot be deserialized by Jackson since this is not an Integer (it seems to be, but it isn't). An Integer object from java.lang Integer is a little more complex.

For your Postman request to work, simply put (without curly braces { }):

```
3
```

Comment: I know this is late but how can I make my controller method to send the request like
`{
    "userId": 3
}`

Comment: @Gimnath Send `{ "userId": "{{userIdVariable}}" }`, wrapped in quotes and with *no* spaces between the variable name and the braces.