# Cannot deserialize instance of int[] out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot

Hello guys I want to send Array of int and String as RequestBody:
This is the json:

```
{
    "customUiModel": [1, 3, 5],
    "user": "user"
}
```

This is the endpoint code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
     public CustomUiModel createCustomUiObject(@RequestBody @Valid int[] customUiModel, String user) {

    return customAppService.saveCustom(customUiModel, user);
}
```

And this is the error :

> "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance ofint[]out
>   of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance ofint[]out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source:
>   (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]", "path": "/custom/save"

I have tried with Array instead this int[] but I have got same error...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START\_OBJECT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471005/jsonmappingexception-can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-lang-integer-out-of-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an object instead of `int[], String` to hold them,

```
public class Example {
    private int[] customUiModel;
    private String user;
}
```

and change controller method to,

```
public CustomUiModel createCustomUiObject(@RequestBody @Valid Example exe) {}
```

Comment: The json should stay same?

Comment: @xmlParser yes, `customUiModel` and `user`, does it change on same request ?

Comment: I will try now but I think it wont work with the same json

Comment: Everything is okay sir. Thank you!

Comment: Can someone tell why the object class worked in this case? thanks in advance.