# Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, jackson-databind

Here is my Controller mapping for put request:

```
@PutMapping("/voteForPostByUser")
    public String vote(@RequestParam(value = "postId", required = 
true) String postId, @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) 
Integer userId, @RequestBody Boolean vote) {

        BlogPostVoteDTO blogPostVoteDTO = new BlogPostVoteDTO 
(postId, userId, vote);
        return 
this.blogPostService.updateBlogPostVotes(blogPostVoteDTO);  
}
```

When I run the following request from POSTMAN:

```
http://localhost:8082/microblog/api/voteForPostByUser?postId=5d564a2638195729900df9a6&userId=5

Request Body:
{
        "vote" : true
    }
```

I get the following exception

```
"status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of 
`java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot 
deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token\n 
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
    "trace": 
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON 
parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of 
START_OBJECT token; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot 
deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token\n 
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]\r\n\tat
```

I is probably something simple, but I don't get what am I missing ?

Comment: at first sight, the issue is that you are trying to convert the entire body request to a Boolean while the actual Boolean is just the inner field. If you create a class VoteRequest with a Boolean vote field in it, it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot deserialize instance of int\[\] out of START\_OBJECT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222578/cannot-deserialize-instance-of-int-out-of-start-object-token)

Comment: If so, this one should work: 
    http://localhost:8082/microblog/api/voteForPostByUser?postId=5d564a2638195729900df9a6&userId=5&vote=true 
    @PutMapping("/voteForPostByUser")
     public String vote(@RequestParam(value = "postId", required = true) 
    String postId, @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) Integer 
    userId, @RequestParam(value = "vote", required = true) Boolean vote) {
  ...
     }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try on postman using true or false like this.It's ok.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You just need to send `true` or `false` as the body of the request, no need for curly braces or key-value structure

Answer (score 4):

Create a new class for your payload:

```
  class Payload {
    Boolean vote;
    // maybe some getters/setter here
  }
```

and use it as your `RequestBody`

```
@PutMapping("/voteForPostByUser")
public String vote(@RequestParam(value = "postId", required = true) String postId, @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) Integer userId, @RequestBody Payload payload) {
    boolean vote = payload.vote; //or payload.getVote()
    BlogPostVoteDTO blogPostVoteDTO = new BlogPostVoteDTO(postId, userId, vote);
    return this.blogPostService.updateBlogPostVotes(blogPostVoteDTO);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You expect a boolean from your `@RequestBody Boolean vote` however JSON sends text. You can either use the Payload class as suggested already but you can also simply change your controller to expect a String like this `@RequestBody String vote` and convert that string into boolean using `Boolean.valueOf(vote)` to be able to use it where you need it.